# How to compile ffmpeg with rm/rmvb support?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, decoding, libavcodec

I googled around and found no solution. What's the specific arguments to compile the newest version FFMPEG to support rm,rmvb format video? I am new in video proccessing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: ok you mean Real Video. Do you want decode or encode?

Comment: RealVideo 4.0.Only decoding is needed.

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg has Real Video 3.0/4.0 decode support only. It should be available by default. 
Run: `ffmpeg -codecs | grep RealVideo` . You should get a output as below:

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 25 2013 15:16:27 with llvm_gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.11.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=/usr/bin/llvm-gcc --host-cflags='-Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7' --host-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
 DEV D  rv10            RealVideo 1.0
 DEV D  rv20            RealVideo 2.0
 D V D  rv30            RealVideo 3.0
 D V D  rv40            RealVideo 4.0
```

If you notice RealVideo 3.0 and 4.0 have Decode(D) option available.

Comment: Thank you. FFMPEG support real video format.But when I run my programm in Opencv using ffmpeg as video io support following error occurs：[rm @ 0x1982df80] Invalid stream index 2 for index at pos 21395702
video has 24088frames
get sample position
[rv40 @ 0x198e0b40] Internal error, picture buffer overflow Why？